# Finding string that matches specific requirements

Tags: string, algorithm, go

There is a function that should return `true`:

```
func accessible(agent string) bool {
  a := strings.Split(agent, " ")
  if len(a) != 3 { return false }
  b := a[0]
  c := a[1]
  d := a[2]
  x := strings.EqualFold(b, c)
  y := b != strings.ToLower(c)
  z := strings.Index(d, b+c) == 1 && len(d) == 5
  return x && y && z
}
```

However I can't figure out which `string` input will match these requirements. Am I missing something?

PS: This is task #3 from gocode.io

Comment: "Aa AA aAaAA" may work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`agent` must be 3 "words", 3 parts separated by spaces:

```
a := strings.Split(agent, " ")
if len(a) != 3 { return false }
```

1st and 2nd words must match case insensitive:

```
x := strings.EqualFold(b, c)
```

But not case sensitive:

```
y := b != strings.ToLower(c)
```

And 3rd word must contain the first 2 concatenated:

```
z := strings.Index(d, b+c) == 1 && len(d) == 5
```

Starting at index `1` (prepend with any character) and must contain 5 chars (5 bytes) (postpend to have 5 chars/bytes).

**Example:**

```
fmt.Println(accessible("A a _Aa__"))
```

**Prints:**

```
true
```